# Port forwarding

Tags: port-forwarding

I have a paid web host on godaddy, I would like to know if it is possible that I use a custom port to redirect to a specific folder on the server (ex: a web mail server or a private folder)

Comment: This question is nonsensical, sorry.

Comment: @Sirex - in what way? It was perfectly clear to me.

Comment: in that it makes no sense. custom port ? private folder ?

Comment: @Sirex: What I was willing to do is installing a mail server then use a specific unused port rather than 80 so that only employees use to access the mail server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a dedicated server and you have full root access (or at least access to do as you wish with apache), then sure, this should be quite simple.

Say, for instance, you wanted to associate port 8888 with a certain directory...in your main apache config file (apache.conf or httpd.conf), add:

```
Listen 8888
NameVirtualHost *:8888
```

Then add a VirtualHost:

```
<Virtualhost *:8080>
    ServerName foo.example.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/directory
</VirtualHost>
```

I haven't tested this, so I'm not sure it's 100% correct, but it's very close, and you should be able to adapt it to your environment.

Comment: how can this be done?

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect your additional question.